# javascript adding variables on top

Tags: javascript

Okay this should be a simple one

```
            var width1 = size3 + 275 ; // adding more
            var width2 = 225 - size1; // subtracting width
```

width2 is coming out fine, for example if size1 = 4 width2 = 221. However if size3 is 4 the width1 comes out 4275. It keeps adding it to the front or back. I don't know why. ( I have flipped the size3 + 275, back and forth {275+size3} even put '275' in quotes.

Thanks for your help

Comment: common problem. You're adding to a string. Use `+size3 + 275`

Comment: Or you could multiply it by 1, var width1 = size3 * 1 + 275.
I don't know which method has least overhead...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The size value is treated as a string because it's in quotes, use [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to turn it into an integer:

```
var width1 = parseInt(size3, 10) + 275 ; // adding more
var width2 = 225 - parseInt(size1, 10); // subtracting width
```

If size is a string the `+` operator is used to concatenate rather than add.

Comment: Thanks you very much. Was thinking something like that. Although I did not know parseInt could fix it.